# I Copied MID files from Yamaha Keyboard, but Playback is Different

Tags: audio-recording, recording, midi, keyboard, playback

I am a newbie in sound design and digital musical instrument stuff.

Recently, me and my friend recorded an instrument using some Yamaha Keyboard. When we play that recording on a Yamaha Keyboard, and sounds perfect.

I then copied the .MID recorded files from that Yamaha Keyboard and tried to play them on my laptop using general music player. It sounds so different.

I was struggling to make that sound the same, and don't know what software or tools to use. I am completely lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A MIDI file only contains information on which notes you're playing. The sound attached to each note is not part of the file (which is why a MIDI file is much smaller than an audio file).

What you're looking for is a sound module or [software synthesizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_synthesizer) that can replicate the sound of your Yamaha keyboard.

One common format for this is a [VST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Studio_Technology) plugin - a standardized format that allows you to add a software synthesizer to many different audio workstation programs. 
You'd have to try and find a VST plugin that contains the sounds of your Yamaha synth.

Or play back the MIDI file through your Yamaha keyboard, and record the sound using a microphone or the keyboard's line outputs.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but can you recommend some software synthesizer? I am very noob on this :(

Comment: I've no experience with this either, so all I can do is point you in the general direction.

Comment: Ok thanks, hope you doing well